# boundary of the boundary of a set is empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am learning some stuff about the interior, closure and boundary of sets $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ and I am wondering about the following:

1) $\partial\partial A=\partial A$ ?

2) $\partial\partial\partial A=\partial A$ ?

3) $\partial\partial A=\emptyset$ ?

---

So 1) is false for e.g. $A=\mathbb Q$ with $\partial A=\mathbb R\neq\emptyset=\partial\partial A$

2) and 3) seems kinda hard. I guess 3) is wrong but I don't have a counterexample.

So does anybody have an idea about 2) and 3) ?

---

Add: A point $x$ is a boundary point of a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ and $A^c$.

Comment: You should include the definition of boundary.

Comment: 2) falls down with the same example, and 3) falls down for $A$ a singleton set, for example (any closed or open set $A$ has $\partial \partial A = \partial A$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the second question, when $A = \mathbb{Q}$, $\partial A = \mathbb{R}$ and $\partial\partial A = \emptyset $ and $\partial\partial\partial A = \emptyset$ as well.

For the third, example, consider the open interval $A = (-1,1)$ then $\partial A = \{-1,1\}$ and $\partial\partial A = \{-1,1\} \neq \emptyset$.